# Error in assigning observeEvent to a variable (in order to destroy later)

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble assigning an observeEvent or observe to a variable

e.g.

```
        print("hello")
      })
```

Seems to be ok

But

```
  session$test<-observeEvent(input$creditLevelSelector,{
        
        
        
        updatePickerInput(
          session,
          inputId="creditValues",
          choices = unique(data()[[input$creditLevelSelector]])
          
        )
      })
```

Gives an error:

```
Error in $<-.session_proxy: Attempted to assign value on session proxy.
```

Any ideas what exactly this error means?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign it to the `session` object? That shouldn't be necessary. You should just be able to define a variable in the server.

Comment: @MrFlick because the observes are in a module which can be called and removed. When it's called the second time it duplicates the observe events so I need a way to get the observe variables accessible to the main server so I can use the $destory

Comment: Your question didn't mention modules at all. Then maybe you want to put that in the `session$userData` environment. But you can't just assign to `session`. That's not allowed. It would easier to help if you turned your problem into a minimal reproducible example so we could actually run and test the code to see if has the behavior you desire.